# canvas game - most efficient way to store/calculate position/iterate over particles/bullets/game elements

Tags: javascript, canvas

Let's say that I'd like to store all the bullets, that anyone is shooting in my game to calculate new position every frame etc.

If there are 10 players and everyone's shot rate is 10 shots per second we would possibly need to track 1000 objects after only 10 seconds.

We do know, that iteration over array is very efficient.

should I add new bullets like this?

```
// "bullets" is an array
bullets.push({
    x_position: 5, // x position from which bullet was shot
    y_position: 10, // same as above but for y
    x_speed: 2, // count of pixels that bullet is travelling on x axis per frame
    y_speed: 10 // as above but for y
});
```

should I remove bullets, that hit the bound, or another player like this?

```
delete bullets[i] // i -> currently processed bullet index
```

Cause if i try to take out the element from bullets array, it's not very efficient with long arrays.

Honestly i haven't had any better idea to solve bullets problem. Iteration through this kind of array can be painful after couple of minutes because if we delete old bullets, the array length just stays the same and we end up with iterating over milions of records, from which 99% are just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to implement a linked list instead of using a JavaScript array.

## The truth about JS arrays

First, you may have a misconception about arrays. When we think of JavaScript arrays, we're really talking about hashmaps where the keys just happen to be integers. That's why arrays can have non-numeric indices:

```
L = [];
L[1] = 4
L["spam"] = 2;
```

Iteration is fast for arrays (in the C/C++ sense, at least), but iteration through a hashmap is rather poor.

In your case, some browsers might implement your array a real array if [certain constraints](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/) are met. But I'm fairly certain you don't want a real array either.

## Array performance

Even a real array isn't particularly amenable to what you want to do (as you pointed out, your array just keeps filling up with `undefined` elements, even as you delete bullets!)

And imagine if you did want to delete bullets from a real array and remove the `undefined` elements: the most efficient algorithm I can think of involves creating a new array after a full sweep of bullets, copying all the bullets which haven't been deleted into this new array. This is fine, but we can do better.

## Linked Lists in JavaScript!

Based on your problem, I think you want the following:

- fast creation
- fast iteration
- fast deletion

A simple data structure which provides constant time creation, iteration, and deletion is a linked list. (That said, linked lists don't allow you to get random bullets quickly. If that is important to you, use a tree instead!)

So how do you implement a linked list? My favorite way is to give each object a `next` reference, so that each bullet points or "links" to the next bullet in the list.

### Initializing

Here's how you might start the linked list off:

```
first_bullet = {
    x_position: 5,
    y_position: 10,
    x_speed: 2,
    y_speed: 10,
    next_bullet: undefined, // There are no other bullets in the list yet!
};

// If there's only one bullet, the last bullet is also the first bullet.
last_bullet = first_bullet;
```

### Appending

To add a bullet to the end of the list, you'll want to set the `next` reference of the old `last_bullet`, then move `last_bullet`:

```
new_bullet = {
    x_position: 42,
    y_position: 84,
    x_speed: 1,
    y_speed: 3,
    next_bullet: undefined, // We're going to be last in the list
};

// Now the last bullet needs to point to the new bullet
last_bullet.next_bullet = new_bullet;

// And our new bullet becomes the end of the list
last_bullet = new_bullet;
```

### Iterating

To iterate through the linked list:

```
for (b = first_bullet; b; b = b.next_bullet) {

    // Do whatever with the bullet b

    // We want to keep track of the last bullet we saw...
    // you'll see why when you have to delete a bullet
    old = b; 
}
```

### Deleting

Now for deletion. Here, `b` represents the bullet being deleted, and `old` represents the bullet just before it in the linked list --- so `old.next_bullet` is equivalent to `b`.

```
function delete_bullet(old, b) {
    // Maybe we're deleting the first bullet
    if (b === first_bullet) {
        first_bullet = b.next_bullet;
    }

    // Maybe we're deleting the last one
    if (b === last_bullet) {
        last_bullet = old;
    }

    // Now bypass b in the linked list
    old.next_bullet = b.next_bullet;
};
```

Notice that I didn't delete the bullet using `delete b`. That's because [`delete` doesn't do what you think it does.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/)

Comment: Now i'm thinking, where, beside resources from your answer, could I learn this kind of "performance tricks" and ways to solve common game coding problems. Any tips? :)

Comment: I wouldn't call the use of linked lists a "performance trick" so much as a choice of data structure. Different data structures are good at different things, and choosing a data structure is one of the most substantial changes you can make in code.

My answer contains two links to websites with cheesy V8-specific performance tricks, although these tricks won't necessarily make things faster for Firefox or IE users.

@rezoner's answer also contains one important trick. Instead of updating every object every frame, just mark changed objects as dirty and update only dirty objects when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to removing the bullets or any objects in collections. Never found it to be a bottleneck of a game - it is always the rendering.

### Game

```
game = {
  dirty: false,
  entities: [ ],
  clean: function() {
    this.dirty = false;
    clean(this.entities, "_remove");
  },
  step: function() {
    if(this.dirty) this.clean();
  }
}
```

### Bullet

```
Bullet = function() { 
  this._remove = false;
}

Bullet.prototype = {
  kill: function() {
    this.game.dirty = true;
    this._remove = true;
  }
}
```

### Cleaning function

```
function clean(array, property) {

  var lastArgument = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  var isLastArgumentFunction = typeof lastArgument === "function";

  for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(array[i] === null || (property && array[i][property])) {
      if(isLastArgumentFunction) {
        lastArgument(array[i]);
      }
      array.splice(i--, 1);
      len--;
    }
  }
}
```